# Empty passphrase for private SSH key works with `ssh-add` but NOT `ssh-keygen`

Tags: ssh

I have a private SSH key that is encrypted with an empty pass phrase:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC
...
```

I know it is empty because if I use `ssh-add`, it prompts me for the passphrase and leaving it empty works. If I give `ssh-add` a phony phrase, it gives me the expected error message `Bad passphrase, try again for id_rsa_old`.

However, when I try to use `ssh-keygen -p` to change the pass phrase, it gives me the error `incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key`. Any ideas on how I can change the passphrase, or even why `ssh-add` allows the empty phrase and `ssh-keygen` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> encrypted with an empty pass phrase

An empty passphrase would be no encryption. The `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED` tells you it is encrypted with a passphrase.

> if I use `ssh-add`, it prompts me for the passphrase

If ssh-add prompts you for a passphrase, that means the key has a passphrase. It would not prompt if the key had no passphrase.

> leaving it empty works

Please clarify what you mean by "works". It would display `Identity added` if it worked. This should not happen if no passphrase was provided.

> Any ideas on how I can change the passphrase

You have to provide the old passphrase to `ssh-keygen`.

> why `ssh-add` allows the empty phrase

It doesn't. Please check which keys have actually been added with `ssh-add -L`.

Comment: Ah, after I `ssh-add` and press enter, it echos nothing (no `Identity added`) and `ssh-add -L` confirms this. Thanks. I was assuming that because it echoed nothing (no error message), that the key was added.